# Is it possible to reload a python module as something?

Tags: python, reload, interpreter

Messing around in the interpreter, it would be useful for me to be able to do something along the lines of `reload(foo) as f`, though I know it is not possible. Just like I do `import foo as f`, is there a way to do it?

Using Python 2.6

Thanks!

Comment: You can just reassign; `f = foo`.

Comment: I cannot believe in my stupidity... Thanks.

Comment: It isn't a stupid question of how to handle aliases when reloading!

Comment: What if you just want to reload a specific function, like: `from lib import foo` How do you reload that function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you import as `import foo as f` in the first place, then the reload call can be `reload(f)`

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 Answer

As others have said, just reload using the name you used as an alias. However, since `imp` is deprecated in Python 3, you should now do this with `importlib`. Let's say your original import used an alias as follows:

`import fullLibName as aliasName`

Then to reload the alias:

```
importlib.reload(aliasName)
```

Or (more standard usage):

```
from importlib import reload
...
reload(aliasName)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import foo
f = reload(foo)
```

This should work, if I understand your question right.

If you don't actually need to reload the library, you can do as Martijn suggested, and just re-assign foo.

```
f = foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`imp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) gives you more access to import internals, and you can import any source file (i.e. it doesn't need to be in the path).

E.g.

```
anyname = imp.load_source("SOME NAME", FILEPATH)
```